# php html tags converted to string

Tags: php, html, dom, html-entities

I am trying to process a HTML file with php as a DOM document. Processing is okay, but when I save the html document with $html->saveHTMLFile("file_out.html"); all link tags are converted from:

```
Click here: <a title="editable" href="http://somewhere.net">somewhere.net</a>
```

to

```
Click here: &lt;a title="editable" href="http://somewhere.net"&gt; somewhere.net &lt;/a&gt;
```

I process the links as php scripts, maybe this makes a difference?
I cannot convert the `&lt;` back to < with htmlentitites_decode() or such. Is there any other conversion or encoding I can use?

The php script looks like the following:

```
<?php
$text = $_POST["textareaX"];
$id = $_GET["id"];
$ref = $_GET["ref"];
$html = new DOMDocument(); 
$html->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$html->formatOutput       = false;
$html->substituteEntities = false;
$html->loadHTMLFile($ref.".html"); 
$elem = $html->getElementById($id); 
$elem->nodeValue = $innerHTML;

if ($text == "")
  { $text = "--- No details. ---"; }
$newtext = "";
$words = explode(" ",$text);
foreach ($words as $word) {
  if (strpos($word, "http://") !== false) {
    $newtext .= "<a alt=\"editable\" href=\"".$word."\">".$word."</a>"; 
    }
  else {$newtext .= $word." ";}
}

$text = $newtext;

function setInnerHTML($DOM, $element, $innerHTML) {
  $node = $DOM->createTextNode($innerHTML);
  $children = $element->childNodes;
  foreach ($children as $child) {
    $element->removeChild($child);
  }
  $element->appendChild($node);
}

setInnerHTML($html, $elem, $text);
$html->saveHTMLFile($ref.".html");
header('Location: '."tracking.php?ref=$ref&user=unLock");
?>
```

We get the reference to a file from "id" and "ref" and the input data from array "textareaX". Next I open the file, identify the html element by id and replace its content (a link) with the input data from the textarea. I provide only the href in the textarea and the script builds the hyperlink from that. Next I plug this back into the original file and overwrite the input file.

When I write the new file though, the link `<a href= ...> </a>` is converted to `&lt;a href=...&gt; &lt;/a&gt;`, which is a problem.

Comment: The same code wiorks for me.

I have used `$html = new DOMDocument(); 
$html->loadHTMLFile("file_in.html"); 
$html->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$html->formatOutput       = true;
$html->saveHTMLFile("file_out.html"); 
`

Comment: Hi @Jack! Maybe I did not provide enough information. I edited my question and now include the whole script. The problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is part of your code with the issue identified:

```
<?php

function setInnerHTML($DOM, $element, $innerHTML) {
  /*********************************
      Well, there's your problem:
  **********************************/
  $node = $DOM->createTextNode($innerHTML);
  $children = $element->childNodes;
  foreach ($children as $child) {
    $element->removeChild($child);
  }
  $element->appendChild($node);
}

?>
```

What you are doing is passing your new anchor (a) tag as a string then creating a text node out of it (text is just that - text, not HTML). The createTextNode function automatically encodes any HTML tags so that they will be visible as text when viewed by a browser (this is so you can present HTML as visible code on your page if you choose to).

What you need to do is create the element as HTML (not a text node) then append it:

```
<?php

function setInnerHTML($DOM, $element, $innerHTML) {

  $f = $DOM->createDocumentFragment();
  $f->appendXML($innerHTML);
  $element->appendChild($f);

}

?>
```

Comment: No problem, glad I could help